# Understanding va_list in Variadic Functions: gp_offset Incrementation, fp_offset Fixation, and Garbage Values

Tags: c, variadic-functions

In variadic functions, the `va_list` type is often implemented as an array of structs, where each array element holds a struct with the following definition:

```
typedef struct {
   unsigned int gp_offset;
   unsigned int fp_offset;
   void *overflow_arg_area;
   void *reg_save_area;
} va_list[1];
```

I noticed interesting behavior when using `va_list` in a simple code snippet:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void example_function(int arg_count, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, arg_count);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < arg_count) {
      printf("%d\n", va_arg(args, int));
      i++;
    }

    va_end(args);
}

int main() {
    example_function(3, 1, 2, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

In this code:

1. The `gp_offset` starts at 8 and increments by 8 with each call to va_arg in the while loop.
2. The `fp_offset` remains fixed at 48.
3. `overflow_arg_area` and `reg_save_area` are initialized with garbage values.

I would like to understand:

- Why does `gp_offset` increment by 8 with each `va_arg` call?
- Why is `fp_offset` fixed at 48?
- Why do `overflow_arg_area` and `reg_save_area` point to garbage values?

Comment: These are all implementation details of your specific system, as the C standard does not dictate how `va_list` is implemented.  You would need to look at the source code of your system, assuming it's available.

Comment: What operating system and architecture are you using?

Comment: Those numbers represent how the implementation stores variadic arguments in the stack frame. 8 is presumably the size of the largest possible argument (I guess structures are passed using a pointer). `overflow_arg_area` is probably only used when the number of arguments exceeds some threshold.

Comment: `Why does gp_offset increment by 8 with each va_arg call?` How are you checking that? `Why is fp_offset fixed at 48?` How are you checking that? `Why do overflow_arg_area and reg_save_area point to garbage values?` How have you determined that? How have you differentiated garbage value from a real value? I do not know really how to write a coherent answer. You might be interested in https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf pages 52 - 55.